# Flutter Stream Provider doesn't provider the stream of data when I update the variable

Tags: flutter, dart, provider

I use provider for state management. I when I update the keyword variable, but stream provider doesn't update the value or fetch the data or update UI. How can I do that?

I use backend search for product filtering. So how can search and filter product Using stream provider.

`

```
class FilterProvider extends ChangeNotifier {
  String? _keyword;

  getkeyword(String value) {
    _keyword = value;
    filterFetchService();
    print(_keyword);
  }

  Stream<GetFiltersProductModel> filterFetchService() async* {
    print(_keyword);
    QueryResult queryResult = await qlclient.query(
      QueryOptions(
        document: gql(QueryDocument.filters),
        variables: {
          "productPrams": {
            "search": _keyword??"",
            "visibility": true,
            "approved": true,
          }
        },
      ),
    );
    Map<String, dynamic> data = queryResult.data as Map<String, dynamic>;

    var body = GetFiltersProductModel.fromJson(data);
    if (kDebugMode) {
      print(data);
    }

    yield body;
  }
}
```

`

I refetch the product and update the ui when keyword variable is updated.

Comment: If i use filterFetchService to get keyword, it's need when I start the provider how can i update the data. I am new Please give me some example for filtering data.

Comment: The method notifylisteners() will update the three to show new values.

Comment: It update the value but stream doesn't update the UI and fiterfetchservice() doesn't run. Can you share some example